# Understanding “undefined” in Javascript: how it works, how to safely check against it and whether reassignment is possible

Tags: javascript, undefined

I’ve been reading about `undefined` in JavaScript and now I am not sure if my understanding is correct. There is a lot of talk around how to check for `undefined` but somehow I couldn’t find any mentioning of something that to me seems fundamental to understanding of how `undefined` actually works (`undefined` being property on host object). This is the reason for this question, I need to confirm that what I understand is correct and if I’m wrong I would appreciate clarification.

Okay, first of all, `undefined` is property on host object (`window` in browsers) so it’s perfectly legal to use:

```
window.undefined
```

The value of this property is type `"undefined"`. This is one of the JavaScript types along with `Object`, `String`, `Number` and `Null`. So if I do:

```
if(someVar===undefined) {}
```

I’m actually checking against `window.undefined` property, whatever it contains, is that right?

So this code below would be pretty dumb as this would check `someVar` only against the string `"undefined"`, not the type nor the property of the `window` object, right?

```
if(someVar==='undefined') {}
```

This below would be also incorrect as this would check against the `window.undefined` property (whatever it contains):

```
if(typeof someVar===undefined) {}
```

So, to sum it up, the only proper and cross-browser way to check for undefined is to use `typeof` e.g.:

```
if(typeof someVar==='undefined')
```

Is that right?

Also in ES5 `window.undefined` cannot be reassigned but it’s perfectly legal in older browsers right?

This however can still be done and is evil if my understanding is right:

```
(function() { 
  var undefined=66;
  alert(undefined);
})()
```

I would appreciate clarification if I misunderstood how `undefined` works in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes to everything you said. I think you understood all there is to know about `undefined`.

Comment: The statement "undefined is property on host object (window in browsers)" is sort of correct. There is an [undefined Type](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.10) whose only value is the *undefined* value. There is also an *undefined* property of the [**Global object**](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1), which is a [built–in object](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.7). In browsers, the *window* object (a [host object](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.8)) is effectively an alias for the Global object.

Comment: `Null` is not a JavaScript type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost correct. Except for this:

> The value of [window.undefined] is type "undefined". This is one of Javascriupt types along with Object, String, Number, and Null

There are 3 `undefined` in javascript. The global variable `undefined`, the value `undefined` and the type `undefined`.

Even if the global variable `undefined` is overridden, the value `undefined` still exists. There are several ways to get it one of which is an empty argument to a function, another is a variable declaration without assigning anything:

```
// Note: Probably need older browsers to assign to undefined:
window.undefined = 1;

(function(foo){ // the value of foo is undefined;
    var bar;    // the value of bar is undefined;

    return [foo === bar, foo === window.undefined]; // returns [true,false]
})();
```

Note carefully that in the example above we're checking the value, not the type. Yes `===` checks type and value but if you replace `===` with `==` the result would be the same.

The value `undefined` has type `undefined` ('Undefined' in the spec and documentation but typeof returns 'undefined') and type `undefined` is only valid for the value `undefined`.

Comment: Minor nitpick: the type name is Undefined, not undefined.

Comment: Well, `typeof` returns 'undefined' not 'Undefined' but yes, ES262 calls it Undefined.

Comment: _“There are 3 undefined in javascript. The global variable `undefined` […]”_: you mean the _property_ `undefined` _of the global object_, right? That’s not exactly the same as a global variable.

Comment: @Xufox: No, I mean the global variable `undefined`. It's just that in js, global variables are also properties of the global object (except of course for the global object itself).

Comment: @slebetman Hm, you’re right, I’ve avoided global variables for such a long time, that I never really noticed that `abc=123;` and `var abc=123;` at the top level both add a property to `window`, only that the `var` version makes that property non-configurable…

Answer (score 4):

That's all fine, plus:

- you can use `void 0` to reliably "generate" the real `undefined` value (or not-a-value; it's kind-of zen)
- in a function, you can reference an argument that you know isn't supplied to get a reliable `undefined`

  ```
  (function( undefined ) {
    // ...
  })();
  ```

  This second example is not really the clearest code in the world, but you'll see it sometimes in common public codebases, tutorials, etc.

Comment: Use `void 0`, don't use that second monstrosity. That's asking for confusion.

Comment: @Cuberto sorry; I agree with you and I should have added more text

Comment: Why not `var undefined;` in an appropriate scope?

Answer (score 2):

> So if I do:
>
> ```
> if(someVar===undefined) {}
> ```
>
> I'm actually checking against window.undefined property whatever it
>   contains is that right?

Right.

> So this code below would be pretty dumb as this would check `someVar`
>   only against the string undefined, not the type nor the property of
>   window object right?
>
> ```
> if(someVar==='undefined') {}
> ```

Right.

> This below would be also incorrect as this would check against the
>   `window.undefined` property (whatever it contains):
>
> ```
> if(typeof someVar===undefined) {}
> ```

Right.

> So to sum it up, the only proper and cross-browser way to check for
>   undefined is to use typeof e.g.:
>
> ```
> if(typeof someVar==='undefined')
> ```
>
> Is that right?

Yes, though it is error-prone because you may mis-type that string and get no error (even in strict mode) to indicate the mistake.

So it's better to call some method, especially if you're already using some framework e.g. in AngularJS - `angular.isUndefined`

> Also in ES5 window.undefined cannot be reassigned but its perfectly legal in older browsers right?

Right.

> This however can still be done and is evil if I my understanding is
>   right:
>
> ```
> (function() { 
> var undefined=66;
> alert(undefined);
> })()
> ```

I believe so.

Comment: I agree with this answer. However, instead of depending on Angular's functionality (like angular.isUndefined), the current industry standard is lodash.js. You can use lodash with any framework or platform, including Angular.

Comment: @aaronfrost The current industry standard is fine, but I wouldn't add lodash (or any other dependency) if whatever framework your project happens to be using, already has this feature.

Comment: Additionally, there is one last version of undefined not mentioned. If you reference a var that has never been "declared" (I use that term lightly), you won't get a forgiving undefined result. You will get a hard error to a variable that hasn't been reference. E.g. if you say " type foo === 'Number' " but you never declared foo, you would get a hard fail, which is another kind of undefined.

Comment: I would definitely use a lib like lodash. Angular only supports a dozen or so utility methods, while lodash has dozens of dozens, each one there to save you lines upon lines of code.

Comment: *"the current industry standard is lodash.js"* Where did you get that from? *"if you say " type foo === 'Number' " but you never declared foo, you would get a hard fail, which is another kind of undefined"* Nope: http://jsfiddle.net/zLerB/. `typeof` is actually the only way to test for undeclared variables without generating an error (http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3). And there is only *one* `undefined`.

Comment: Forgot to add @aaronfrost ;) See my comment ^^^^^

Answer (score 1):

> So to sum it up, the only proper and cross-browser way to check for undefined is to use typeof e.g.:
>
> `if(typeof someVar==='undefined')`

No, the direct comparison `somevar === undefined` is fine.

There are any number of global variables that can be overwritten or shadowed that will break code. There's no way to protect against them all, except to simply not allow bad code.

---

What's nice about the direct comparison *(aside from being shorter and cleaner)* is that it's must more natural and intuitive, whereas people often get the other syntax wrong. They end up accidentally using the other examples you gave:

```
if (somevar === 'undefined')

if (typeof somevar === undefined)
```

These are *very* common errors, and are much more common than people redefining `undefined`.

---

Furthermore, you'll see things like this:

```
if (typeof somevar === 'undefiend')
```

This is much more subtle, and is hard to spot when surrounded by a bunch of other code. Again, it's a common mistake.

---

Probably the worst is when you see this:

```
if (typeof somevar === 'undefined')
    somevar = "foobar";
```

What's wrong with that? Well, if `somevar` had not been declared, we've now created an implicit global variable. This can be really bad. If we had done a simple comparison, we would have been alerted to the problem with a *ReferenceError*.

Comment: The typo *'undefiend'* should be easily spotted during unit testing as it will almost certainly never be true. And testing the value of an identifier does not tell you whether it's been declared or not (that is impossible for other than global variables as you can't access the local variable object to test it).

Comment: @RobG: Sure, but how many people have unit tests that actually reach every branch of their code? It's still a problem with the syntax that can be avoided by using the more natural `somevar === undefined`.

Comment: @RobG: Why do we want to test if it has been declared? If it hasn't, and it's not global, then we should welcome the *ReferenceError*, not hide it.

Comment: The point of using the `typeof` operator is to avoid reference errors, I would only use it where that was required (e.g. where a variable may or may not exist). In other cases, direct comparison is likely the best solution. A linter will report undeclared variables (if testing and code reviews don't find them first). `typeof` is a bit useless, its use can nearly always be avoided.

Comment: @RobG:  Yeah I agree that it can nearly always be avoided. There should never be a case where a local variable can not be known to exist, and in the case of globals, one can just check the global object. So I don't actually know of any case where `typeof` is needed to test `undefined`.